# How would I extract the formatted text from a cell in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Lets say A1 is a date formatted to "`YYMMDD`" and I enter `7/7/2014` in the cell.
The cells string changes to "`140707`" but the function bar still shows up as `"7/7/2014"`

When I try to write this code:

```
Dim dateCell As String
dateCell = Cells(1, "A")
```

dateCell will equal to `"7/7/2014"` and not "`140707`"

I want the cell to be formatted that way so that when anyone puts in a date, it'll automatically change it to yymmdd. Now how would I get the text dateCell to equal `140707` and not `7/7/2014`?

I would greatly appreciate it!!
Thanks

Comment: What are you actually attempting to do here?  Do you need a custom date format for your worksheet (seems better than running a `Worksheet_Change` macro continuously...) or do you need to simply extract and use the *formatted* text (`.Text` property) from the cell within a VBA routine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the three different ways to get at the value in a cell here.  Put a date in A1, and format it as you format it.

```
Public Sub test()
 Dim r As Range
 Set r = Range("a1")
 MsgBox ("Value:[" & r.Value & "] Value2:[" & r.Value2 & "] Text:[" & r.Text & "]")
End Sub
```

In your case you want the Text.

Answer (score 0):

In VBA, you can declare a variable as type `Date` instead of `String` which will solve that part of the problem.

In Excel, you need to specify a custom number format to "yyMMdd". Excel will understand that this cell is a date from the value that is in it and extract the proper year, month and day and display it as you specified.

Comment: I think he's trying to extract text from a date-formatted cell.  Admittedly `Date` type may well be better, although we don't necessarily know what he's doing with it after this.

Comment: If I declare it as a Date and set it equal to that cell, then the format of the variable will still be 7/7/2014 and not YYMMDD. How can I change the format of the variable to be YYMMDD?

Comment: As I said, you need to set the cell number format to "yyMMdd".